# How is user input converted into a list with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

```
d_num = []
d_num.append(input("Enter a figure to verify if is a Disarium number: "))
```

With the above code, an input of `135` and `print(d_num)`, would return '135' opposed to '1, 3, 5'.

A quick-fix would be, prompt the user to include whitespace or other characters between digits and use the split command. However, that poses a problem because the output calculation is based upon the index of the digit.

For example:

input: 135
output: true, 135 == Disarium number as 1^1 + 3^2 + 5^3 = 135

Is there an easier way to convert user input, despite `type`, into a list?

Comment: `list(input('enter something'))`? It's not clear to me how you want to proceed after that.

Comment: I'm not sure how/ why but the output for the code you provided: enter something: 123
<class 'list'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to know a way to automatically store each digit of the user input as a list item right? Below is the easiest way I can think of:

```
user_input = input("Enter a figure to verify if is a Disarium number: ")
d_num = [digit for digit in user_input]
```

The d_num list will have each digit stored separately and then you can convert it into an integer/float and perform the calculation to identify if its a Disarium number or not.

As @Jérôme suggested in the comment, a much simpler solution would be to simply convert the user input to a list and python handles the work of adding individual characters as a list item.

`d_num = [digit for digit in user_input]` can be written as `d_num = list(user_input)`

Hope that helps

Comment: I've never heard of the enumerate command. And although that allows for a much more elegant solution to my problem than I was envisioning. Your response has perfectly handled what I asked and I appreciate it :)

Comment: `d_num = [digit for digit in user_input]` can be written `list(user_input)`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `list(d_num)` will give you a list of the individual characters that make up the number. From there, you can just go over them, convert them to integers and raise them to the appropriate power:

```
if int(d_num) == sum((int(d[1])**(d[0] + 1) for d in enumerate(list(d_num)))):
    print("%s is a Disarium number" % d_num)
```

**EDIT:**

As  Jean-François Fabre commented, you don't actually need the `list` call - you could enumerate the string's characters directly:

```
if int(d_num) == sum((int(d[1])**(d[0] + 1) for d in enumerate(d_num))):
    print("%s is a Disarium number" % d_num)
```

Comment: I think you can drop list conversion here: `enumerate(list(d_num))` => `enumerate(d_num)`. `enumerate` knows how to iterate on characters of a string already.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre nice catch, thanks! Edited that in to my answer (with the proper attribution, of course)

Comment: wasn't asking that, but okay :)